# Carbon today/tomorrow instead of in x hours

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm using `Carbon` to modify dates in a project. Now I need get the date as today, tomorrow etc. so I tried it with:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::enableHumanDiffOption(\Illuminate\Support\Carbon::ONE_DAY_WORDS);

$date->diffForHumans();
```

But for today and tomorrow I receive string like: `In 5 hours` and not `tomorrow`.

For today i receive: `16 hours ago` and not `today`.

The date is from an `mysql date` column, eg.: `2018-05-29`.

I read that the needed functionality is currently only available for `en` and `fr` but also with `Carbon::setLocale('en');` i don't receive the needed string.

Using the latest version.

Comment: Hmm. Per https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/pull/1240 the `ONE_DAY_WORDS` affects the "one day ago" / "one day from now" words. When you're below the 24 hour threshold and it's switched to hours/minutes/seconds, I don't think it has any effect.

Comment: Is there a way to force Carbon to output it as today/tomorrow without adding a switch if the date is today/tomorrow?

Comment: I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 2):

as far as `Carbon` is concerned I haven't seen `diffForHumans()` returning as Today or Tomorrow. But there is an hack to fulfil your requirements

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$future = $now->addDays(30);
echo $now->diffInDays($now->copy()->addDay());
```

this will return 1 if when dates are of tomorrow, and return 0 when dates are of today so you can now manage it with a simple if statement. For online workaround you can check carbon APIs [here](http://phpio.net/tools/carbon)

Comment: Good idea to add one day although I could not get it working as such. Why are you adding 30 days and not using $future ?